# When during my component lifecycle can I start accessing this.$refs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html5-audio

I'm trying to hook in to some HTML5 audio events when loading the following single-file Vue.js component:

```
<template>
    <audio ref="player" v-bind:src="activeStationUrl" v-if="activeStationUrl" controls autoplay></audio>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['activeStationUrl'],
    data () {
        return {
            // Last media event that was recorded. We don't hook in to all events. More info at
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Cross-browser_audio_basics.
            'lastEvent': null,
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        const eventsToHookInTo = ['loadstart', 'canplay']
        for (var eventToHookInTo in eventsToHookInTo) {
            this.$refs.player.addEventListener(eventToHookInTo, function () {
                this.lastEvent = eventToHookInTo
            })
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

When the line with `this.$refs` triggers, the reference `player` doesn't seem to be registered yet, so this causes an error. What is the correct way to attach these event listeners when the component loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access it in the `mounted` hook. I am guessing the problem is in the `v-if` here. Is there a possibility you can change this to a `v-show`?

If you can not do that you could try using a [$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) method. This should work as well since the actual render of the element does not happen until the next tick.

Comment: I was afraid that changing `v-if` to `v-show` would cause unwanted behavior on the audio element when switching sources, but after testing it seems fine. Both this approach and the `this.$nextTick(function ...)` option seem to work!